# Get an array of future NSDates

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a date picker.

After choosing a time from this I would like to get the dates of the next 64 Mondays.

How would I go about writing a method to take a date and return an NSArray of NSDates for the next 64 Mondays from that date

for e.g.
I picked time 6:45 pm from date picker then I want to fetch next 64 mondays with there time set to that time.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with the close votes.

Comment: yep... this is a decently challenging question; Ayaz, when you say you want to "fetch" the next 64 Mondays, in what form do you want to do the fetching?  NSDates or EKEvents or?

Comment: I agree with Dave (and I'm usually harsh). I tried to edit this to be a bit clearer. I'm assuming the restriction of 64 is based on creating UILocalNotifications. So solutions with repeating notifications might also be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example (ARC):

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"pickerDate: %@", pickerDate);

NSDateComponents *dateComponents;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:pickerDate];
NSInteger firstMondayOrdinal = 9 - [dateComponents weekday];
dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:firstMondayOrdinal];
NSDate *firstMondayDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:pickerDate options:0];

dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setWeek:1];

for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
    [dateComponents setWeek:i];
    NSDate *mondayDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:firstMondayDate options:0];
    NSLog(@"week#: %i, mondayDate: %@", i, mondayDate);
}
```

NSLog output:

pickerDate: 2011-12-09 20:38:25 +0000

week#: 0, mondayDate: 2011-12-12 20:38:25 +0000

week#: 1, mondayDate: 2011-12-19 20:38:25 +0000

week#: 2, mondayDate: 2011-12-26 20:38:25 +0000

week#: 3, mondayDate: 2012-01-02 20:38:25 +0000

 -the remaining 60 here-

Comment: Thanks for the clear reply. thats next 4 mondays. Should I just loop through it 63 times instead of 4?

Comment: I just show the first four, I edited to make this more clear.

Comment: Just curious, where did you get `9` for calculating `firstMondayOrdinal`?

Comment: The days are numbered starting at 1 for Sunday to Monday is 2 + 7 for days in a week = 9.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the `NSDate` from the picker, and keep adding 24*60*60 seconds to it until it's a Monday. Add the resulting date to the result. Continue adding 7*24*60*60 seconds to the last date you added and pushing the result onto the return list until you have all 64 Mondays. Here is how you tell if a `NSDate` falls on Monday:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateOfInterest];
NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
if (weekday == 2) ... // 2 represents Monday
```

EDIT: DaveDeLong pointed out a deficiency in the above algorithm: it will shift the time two times on the days of changing to daylight savings time. Instead of counting seconds manually, use this code to add a day to `NSDate`:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:1]; // Add 1 when searching for the next Monday; add 7 when iterating 63 times 
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
[comps release];
```

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO this doesn't account for daylight savings time!  And the questioner clearly said he wants to keep the same time.

Comment: @DaveDeLong It is somewhat up for discussion if Apple knows daylight savings time judging from past performance. :-)

Comment: @DaveDeLong This should be fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveDeLong That's correct, and that's the intention. The code adds a component that represents "one day" to currentDate in the call to `dateByAddingComponents`. It needs to be in a loop searching for the next Monday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSCalendar to determine what day of the week today (at the chosen time) is; bump it up to get to the next Monday, and then bump that by by 7 days 63 times to get the Mondays you seem to want.